# Setting the contents of the clipboard in AppleScript

Tags: applescript, clipboard

I want to set the contents of the clipboard to a variable. I've done this before, and it should be simple enough, but I'm getting an error.

```
on checkiPadFinished()
    set tempiPadSerial to "b"
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "iTunes"
            keystroke "c" using {command down}
            set tempiPadSerial to the clipboard as string
            if firstiPadSerial is tempiPadSerial then
                return true
            else if firstiPadSerial is "a" then
                set firstiPadSerial to the clipboard as string
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
    return false
end checkiPadFinished
```

Earlier in my code I declare global variables

global XXX, yyy, zzz, firstiPadSerial
set firstiPadSerial to "a"

The call to checkiPadFinished() looks like:

```
set doneiPads to my checkiPadFinished()
```

As far as I can tell everything should work, but instead I'm getting a cryptic error message.

EDIT: without changing anything it's running. I'm at a loss. I wish that I had written down the error message. But I hit the go button for the 10th time and it worked, so I can't even say what the message was.

Comment: «constant hicoorng» appears to be a System Events constant for the color orange  - can you post the actual code you are using?

Comment: Where do you go to find System Events constants? Also, do you know where I can find a list of all the error codes? Google doesn't seem to be good at finding applescript error codes

Comment: The class in your error compiles to "orange" in a System Events tell statement, so looking in the scripting definition file /System/Library/CoreServices/System Events.app/Contents/Resources/SystemEvents.sdef reveals it to be a highlight color in the appearance preferences.  There is a halfway decent error listing in one of the frameworks headers at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/Headers/MacErrors.h - an application can also define its own error codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
  activate application "iTunes"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "iTunes"
        select row 15 of outline 1 of scroll area 2 of window "iTunes"
        keystroke "c" using {command down}
        delay 0.5 -- jackjr300's suggestion
        set xxx to the clipboard
    end tell
end tell
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But the name of the ipod changes as the program runs, so I'm trying to use serial numbers to identify the devices. I thought this would be easy because I can get the serial with a simple copy. Now that I have the serial I just want to put it in a variable and be on my jolly way. But I get that error whenever I try.

Comment: I have. I get the same error. I should also specify, this is not a runtime error. Applescript editor won't let me save, instead saying that I can't set <<constant hicoorng>> to the clipbaord because access isn't allowed.

Comment: Also, I know that I can access the clipboard, because if I tell it to "say the clipboard" it reads me the serial number.

Comment: I'm on 10.6.8 as well, and iTunes 10.6.1, but it claims to be the newest version of iTunes. I tried running my edit to see what would happen, and it's throwing error number -1708 <<event ascrgdut>> --> error number -1708

Comment: Actually, right after posting this it started working. I don't think that I changed anything at all. I'm going to do a final edit of the working code segment. I'm at a loss for what happened.

Comment: I'm getting a different error now, and am wondering if you can help. See edit.

Comment: I have already seen this.

In general the problem is solved by putting a delay after the execution of the shortcut.

try this : 
`keystroke "c" using {command down}    delay 0.1    set tempiPadSerial to the clipboard as string`